# Bundler::GemRequireError and Gem Load Error is: AddDllDirectory failed when switching from Sqlite3 to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I have a project in rails which worked with SQLITE3. I have to move out to POSTGRES, because Heroku needs to.

**Following the docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#running-rails-on-postgres**, here's what I did:

1. changed Gemfile:

from `gem 'sqlite3'` to `gem 'pg'`

*Note: I've also tried `gem 'pg', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'` and `gem 'pg', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.2'`. They all return the same error.*

2. Ran `bundle install` without errors
3. Modified `config/database.yml`

```yaml
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: test_postgres

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_postgres

production:
  <<: *default
  database: test_postgres
```

4. According to the docs,

> Once you’ve installed the pg gem and migrated your config/database.yml

I tried `rails db:migrate` which returned:

```
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'pg'.
Gem Load Error is: AddDllDirectory failed for D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/x64-mingw32
Backtrace for gem load error is:
...
```

*Note: same error shows on* `rake db:migrate`

`rails s` prints out the same error:

```
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'pg'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: AddDllDirectory failed for D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/x64-mingw32
Backtrace for gem load error is:
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:83:in `add_dll_directory_winapi'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:50:in `initialize'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `new'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `add_dll_directory'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:26:in `rescue in <main>'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<main>'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
D:/Fresqui/Documents/Programar/yale-citrus/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
        from D:/Fresqui/Documents/Programar/yale-citrus/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:83:in `add_dll_directory_winapi': AddDllDirectory failed for D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/x64-mingw32 (RubyInstaller::Runtime::DllDirectory::WinApiError)
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/dll_directory.rb:50:in `initialize'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `new'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:12:in `add_dll_directory'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:26:in `rescue in <main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
        from D:/Fresqui/Documents/Programar/yale-citrus/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.so (LoadError)
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:5:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
        from D:/Fresqui/Documents/Programar/yale-citrus/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from D:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I couldn't find anything about the gem being deprecated, nothing in the docs and not many posts with the same error. Any clues?

Comment: I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score 1):

Here is the original answer [link](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg/issues/365#issuecomment-758717354), install postgresql per pacman:

- `ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-postgresql`
- reinstall pg gem `gem install pg`
- run database setup script `rails db:setup`